# can I automate the calculation of the moving average for some data in tcl?

Tags: tcl, moving-average

I wrote a program that calculates the moving average for some data. The problem is that I can't automatize,  I mean if i want to do the process by 10 steps or more it is not smart to write 10 lines  with the terms of exchange.

The section that calculates the moving average by 4 steps is:

```
     set aux  [lindex $line 4]
     set T [lindex $line 1]
     set aux1 [lrange $valores 1 1]
       set valores [lreplace $valores 0 0 $aux1] 
       
     set aux1 [lrange $valores 2 2]
       set valores [lreplace $valores 1 1 $aux1]
     
     set aux1 [lrange $valores 3 3]
       set valores [lreplace $valores 2 2 $aux1]
       
     set aux1 [lrange $valores 4 4]
       set valores [lreplace $valores 3 3 $aux1]
     
       set valores [lreplace $valores 4 4 $aux]
       set promP [avg $valores]
```

I know that i have to use a for loop, but the attempts i have made didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're keeping a window on the data, it's not too difficult. The trick is to make a procedure to do the critical work.

```
set WINDOW_SIZE 10
set storedData {}

proc updateMovingAverage {value} {
    global storedData WINDOW_SIZE

    set storedData [lreplace [list {*}$storedData $value] 0 end-$WINDOW_SIZE]
    return [expr {[tcl::mathop::+ {*}$storedData] / double([llength $storedData])}]
}
```

Or you could create a class:

```
oo::class create MovingAverage {
    variable window size

    constructor {{windowSize 10}} {
        set window {}
        set size $windowSize
    }

    method item {value} {
        set window [lreplace [list {*}$window $value] 0 end-$size]
        return
    }

    method average {} {
        return [expr {[tcl::mathop::+ {*}$window] / double([llength $window])}]
    }
}
```

The class splits apart the adding of an item and the calculating of the average. The latter is a standard pattern in Tcl now. The trick with adding an item is to append the item to a list and then trim off the front of the list if it is larger than the desired window; the `list {*}$thing $value` does the append-an-item, and the `lreplace THING 0 end-$wantedLength` does the prefix trim (it's replacing them with an empty sequence of items).

---

Here's a more efficient version.

```
oo::class create MovingAverage {
    variable window size index

    constructor {{windowSize 10}} {
        set window {}
        set size $windowSize
        set index 0
    }

    method item {value} {
        lset window $index $value
        set index [expr {($index + 1) % $size}]
        return
    }

    method average {} {
        return [expr {[tcl::mathop::+ {*}$window] / double([llength $window])}]
    }
}
```

This uses the fact that, froom 8.6 onwards (entirely coincidentally when classes are integrated), the `lset` command can append an item to a list.

Comment: I guess you could also structure things as a coroutine.

Comment: Added an answer with a coroutine version.

Answer (score 0):

A coroutine version, like Donal mentioned in a comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Tcl 8.6

proc moving_average {{size 10}} {
    set window [list [yield [info coroutine]]]
    set index 0
    while {true} {
        set avg [expr {[tcl::mathop::+ {*}$window] / double([llength $window])}]
        set index [expr {($index + 1) % $size}]
        lset window $index [yield $avg]
    }
}

# Example usage, plus commented-out example usage of Donal's
# class version to compare the two.

#set class_avg [MovingAverage new]
coroutine coro_avg moving_average
for {set n 1} {$n < 20} {incr n} {
#    $class_avg item $n
#    puts "OO: [$class_avg average]"
    puts "coro: [coro_avg $n]"
}
```

It and the class version have the advantage over the standard proc version like Donal's first example in that it doesn't rely on any global variables, so you can have multiple different data sets with different window sizes all being computed at the same time in different coroutines/objects.